# Zend_Service_Twitter: SSL required

Tags: zend-framework, twitter, twitter-oauth

i have a problem with using `Zend_Service_Twitter` (Zend_Framework 1.12). I'm simply trying to post a new status message but i get an error telling me that `SSL is required`. I searched the manual and tried to add different config parameters for the http client or the adapters to use SSL but no luck. Any ideas?

Here's my code (tokens & secrets have the real values).

```
    $userToken  = 'token';
    $userSecret = 'secret';

    $token = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();
    $token->setToken($userToken)->setTokenSecret($userSecret);

    $twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
        'username' => 'user',
        'accessToken' => $token,          
        'consumerKey'    => 'mykey',
        'consumerSecret' => 'mysecret'
    ));
    $response = $twitter->status->update('My new status!!!');
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: exactly the quoted one `SSL is required`

Comment: That error message does not appear anywhere in the ZF1 source code. Do you have any more info - what class & line generates that error? Do you have a stack trace? I'd guess you're missing openssl, but if so I'd expect the error message to be a little less vague.

Comment: It's the response from Twitter, sorry i haven't mentioned that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i found out myself. Actually `Zend_Service_Twitter` in Version 1.12 does not work anymore. The SSL error does simply come from the fact that the URLs of `Zend_Service_Twitter` use `http://` not `https://`. However it still uses the Rest API v1 which is deprecated and therefore even to fix the URLs does not help.